# Java in memory Caching library that support methods with element level ttl

Tags: java, ehcache-3, caffeine-cache, ehcache-2, in-memory-cache

I would like to set the expiry time of a member of an cache.
I want the custom ttl when the object should expire.
I know I can set it for the whole cache, e.g.

```
Cache cache = manager.getCache("MyCache");
CacheConfiguration config = cache.getCacheConfiguration();
config.setTimeToIdleSeconds(60);
config.setTimeToLiveSeconds(120);
config.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(10000);
config.setMaxEntriesLocalDisk(1000000);
```

In Ehcache 2.x, We can set expiry time on the Element we insert in the cache:

Element element = new Element("key1", "value1");
element.setTimeToLive(100);

Do we have any other java open source library like  that support similar feature as above as  Ehcache 3.x doesnot support this.

Ideally I would like to have the following interface:

put(key, value, timeToLive)// enter a key and value with a specified timeToLIve(ttl)

put(key, value) // enter a key value with no timeToLive

Comment: Caffeine has a [callback](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based) approach to favor loading through the cache. That also let’s you can use the additional methods in [Cache.policy()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Policy.VarExpiration.html) such as your put method.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/expiry.html and  https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/eviction-advisor.html?